# Google Play Store Doesn't Open

Tags: google-play-store, logging, system-error

So, in the end of the past year I have finally got to root my china replica (fake) Galaxy SIII

Everything was working just fine, until I remove some app from the `/system/app` directory, because this replica comes with almost no internal space, although I thought I was removing only unnecessary apps. I removed two that should not have been removed, the phone started to act erratically, it would fully start, but the screen just showed the wallpaper a blinked nonstop.

After my first attempt, I tried to solve it, throwing everything back on it, that stopped the blinking screen and showed the apps shortcuts on the main screen again. Then I started removing one app at time interspersed with a reboot. After removing what I didn't want left, except the only two necessary apps, I went to the Play Store, to download some apps and enjoy the new freed up internal space, only to discover that it simply didn't open anymore.

At first it would load, then show the upgrading screen (from market to play store) and when I tapped *continue" the app would just shutdown, and I was back at the app launcher, then I tried again just to even attempt open the app, the screen would change to the loading, but very quickly, it would shutdown again.

After my second attempt, I tried installing apps via ADB, and it worked, and so did the apps, every app that I installed worked just fine, but it wouldn't be updated unless I could find the .apk file and install it again via ABD. What, in some cases, is simply impossible.

Than I found a site, that would send the download link of the .apk file to my email, and I could download it in my phone, which was not an update but it was better than have to install anything via ADB. Then I tried to launch one of those apps, only to discover that my browser would crash with a F/C when I tapped *save* in the download pop-up.

After weeks searching for solutions and for any clue in this issue, I discovered that within the Dropbox's application directory contained a lot of `.txt` files.

Reading these files, I discovered what is causing the malfunction of the Play Store and the download function in the Browser, and it is the same thing. The problem is I don't know what to do to solve this.

Following below are some examples of the `.txt` files:

**Location**: `/data/system/dropbox`

**File name**: `system_app_crash@1357930047501.txt`

```
Process: com.android.vending
Flags: 0xabe45
Package: com.android.vending v8016010 (3.10.10)
Build: sprd/sprdroid_base/hsdroid:2.3.5/MocorDroid2.3.5 W12.20_P12_20121105.115851:user/test-keys

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://downloads/my_downloads
    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:600)
    at com.google.android.finsky.download.DownloadManagerImpl$1.run(DownloadManagerImpl.java:43)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

**File name**: `system_app_wtf@1354930047485.txt`

```
Process: com.android.vending
Flags: 0xabe45
Package: com.android.vending v8016010 (3.10.10)
Subject: Finsky
Build: sprd/sprdroid_base/hsdroid:2.3.5/MocorDroid2.3.5/W12.20_P12_20121105.115851:user/test-keys

android.util.Log$TerribleFailure: [27]
DownloadProgressManager.makeNewCursor: Download progress cursor null: content://downloads/my_downloads
    at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:275)
    at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:254)
    at com.google.android.finsky.utils.FinskyLog.wtf(FinskyLog.java:40)
    at com.google.android.finsky.download.DownloadProgressManager.makeNewCursor(DownloadProgressManager.java:126)
    at com.google.android.finsky.download.DownloadProgressManager.onDownloadProgress(DownloadProgressManager.java:234)
    at com.google.android.finsky.download.DownloadProgressManager.access$000(DownloadProgressManager.java:28)
    at com.google.android.finsky.download.DownloadProgressManager$2.run(DownloadProgressManager.java:97)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

**File name**: `system_app_crash@135793929686111.txt`

```
Process: com.android.browser
Flags: 0x9be45
Package: com.android.browser v10 (2.3.5)
Build: sprd/sprdroid_base/hsdroid:2.3.5/MocorDroid2.3.5/W12.20_P12_20121105.115851:user/test-keys

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://downloads/my_downloads
    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:600)
    at com.android.browser.BrowserActivity.onDownloadStartNoStream(BrowserActivity.java:3737)
    at com.android.browser.BrowserActivity$18.onClick(BrowserActivity.java:3603)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3690)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anyone knows what it means? Or how to solve it? I really want this to work and despite it is taking up all of my free time, and I cannot come up with a solution.

Originally Posted in [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2094550)

Comment: Had a similar problem. My Keyboard constantly crashed with the same error msg. It was a failed dictionary pack download attempt. I del'ed /data/data/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack/*

Comment: Ok, above comment is only meant as a hint/starting point. I guess it's also a dangling / broken app downloads, maybe manually clearing com.android.providers.downloads or so helps. Please let us know if you find out more.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips, the thing is, I don't have the "com.android.providers.downloads" in the "/system/app". I tried to install it and it's not re-install, 'cause I don't know if it was there, cause all the apps I removed, I made a backup, and the only

Comment: I'd say, start by doing a recursive search for download (as root): `grep -ri download /data/data` or so. Then investigate if it could be related. My problem was caused by an unfinished dict-pack download => keyboard broken (with very similar looking err-messages)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips, the thing is, I don't have the "com.android.providers.downloads" in the "/system/app". 
I tried to install it and it's not re-install, 'cause I don't know if it was there, cause all the apps I removed, I made a backup, and the only download related .apk is "DonwloadProviderUi.apk" which is one of the two .apks that I've mentioned, and it's already re-installed.

Comment: Ah: It's maybe that you deleted a package and another has a "content" reference to this package and then fails to resolve it (the reference being in /data/data/pkgname/* somewhere)

Comment: So i tried to install it, but every .apk that I've downloaded to install via ADB returns error messages like "Install Parse Failed No Certificates", "Install Failed Incompatible Shared User" or "Install Failed Older SDK", and when I try to push it, the .apk appear in the "/system/app" directory but after the reboot the phone, and go check the .apk is there but when i touch it the install wizard ask if I want to install it and not overwite the system app, then I tried to install from there, it doesn't even load, just show a check sign and "Application not installed".

Comment: by "install it" I mean the "downloadprovider" (com.android.providers.downloads)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by lack of a system application, the application `donwloadprovider.apk`.

The problem was identified by comparing the `/system/app` directory in two similar devices, and noticing that the application was missing.

The solution:

- Copy the application from the working devic e(A) to a computer.
- Push via ADB the application to the malfunctioning device (B) `/system/app` directory.
- Reboot device B.

Comment: I was going to suggest the download provider app had been deleted, good work :)